How do you open multiple new tabs with target=_blank and have each in a seperate tab?
I know how to open a link in a new tab with target="_blank"
If I have multiple links on a page and they specify target="_blank" clicking one will open in a new tab but if I go back to the page (leaving the new tab open) and click another link, it opens in the same new tab. It reuses the new tab.
Is there a way, if so what is it, to open each link in new tabs and not reuse the new tab?
I want to be able to click all of the links, say eight links, and have eight new tabs open with each link in a separate new tab.
Can this be done? If so, how?
I'm thinking that if there is no way to do this, I'll have to use the open function with other statements and specify a name for the new window. Making them unique should prevent them from being used.

If you specify a unique target value,like 1blank, for each target each link will open in a new tab and the tabs won't be reused by other links.
It may be ugly and nonstandard, but it serves my purpose.
I don't see any errors in the console after trying this. I'm guessing this is taking the name I use in the target=, looks for a tab with that name, if found the tab is reused.
If not found, a new tab is created.
I am using the href value as the target value and everything seems to be working as I want it to.
Perhaps the using of a unique target which equates to a window name is an undocumented matter.

When I say I'm using the href value as target name, I mean the location part of the href value or    href='http://qeee.net --- i use geee.net

Don't use a dash (-) in the target name, it appears the target value will not work as you want it. Example: target="my-name"    it actually appears that only the part of the name up to and excluding the dash is used as the target name.     target="my-name2" will work just like target="my-name"

Another thing I encountered - target= apparently has a length limit - no I did not take the time to determine that limit. I discovered this when I used two URLs that were the same up to a point and they opened in the same tab. Use something else for the target value -- I wound up simply use one, two,three, etc.
